# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}}$is also convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let sequence $a_{n}>0$, $n\in N^{+}$, and such
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}$ convergent. Show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+\cdots+a^2_{n}}$$ is also convergent?

Jack A related result: maybe I guess this also is hold?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k^2}{a^2_{1}+\cdots+a^2_{k}}\le\left(\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}\right)^2$$

Comment: A related result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214634/prove-that-sum-k-1n-frac2k1a-1a-2-a-k4-sum-k-1n-frac1a-k

Comment: But my problem is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{a^2_{1}+\cdots+a^2_{n}}$

Comment: @NewZealand that doesn't stop the link from being related (which it is)

Comment: This is useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599999/the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-n-frac1a-1-frac1a-2-dotsb-fra?rq=1

Comment: Note the proof from Hardy's inequality can be adapted if you add the stronger hypothesis $n=O(a_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Polya-Knopp's inequality (that is an instance of Hardy's inequality for negative exponents) states that for any $p\geq 1$ and for every positive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ we have:

$$ \frac{N^{\frac{p+1}{p}}}{(p+1)\left(a_1^p+\ldots+a_N^p\right)^{1/p}}+\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{n}{a_1^p+\ldots+a_n^p}\right)^{1/p} \leq (1+p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n},\tag{1}$$
hence by taking $p=2$ it follows that:

$$ \sum_{n= 1}^{N}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2}}\leq \sqrt{3}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}\tag{2} $$

Now we re-write the LHS of $(2)$ by partial summation.

Let $Q_n^2\triangleq a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2$ and $h(n)\triangleq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt{n}}{Q_n}=\frac{h(N)}{Q_N}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}h(n)\left(\frac{1}{Q_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{Q_n}\right)=\frac{h(N)}{Q_N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}h(n)\frac{a_{n+1}^2}{Q_n Q_{n+1}(Q_{n+1}+Q_n)} $$
since $h(n)\geq\frac{2}{3}n^{3/2}$, it follows that:

$$ \frac{2N\sqrt{N}}{Q_N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{n^{3/2} a_{n+1}^2}{Q_{n+1}^3}\leq 3\sqrt{3}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{a_n}.\tag{3}$$
If we let $g(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$ and apply partial summation to the original series we get:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n^2}{Q_n^2}=\frac{g(N)}{Q_N^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}g(n)\frac{a_{n+1}^2}{Q_n^2 Q_{n+1}^2}\tag{4}$$
hence by $(3)$ we just need to show that $\frac{g(n)}{Q_n Q_{n+1}}$ is bounded by some constant times $\frac{h(n)}{Q_n+Q_{n+1}}$, or:

$$ g(n)\left(Q_n+ Q_{n+1}\right) \leq K \cdot h(n) Q_n Q_{n+1} $$ 
or:
$$ \frac{1}{Q_n}+\frac{1}{Q_{n+1}}\leq K\cdot\frac{h(n)}{g(n)} \tag{5}$$
that follows from the fact that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{Q_n}$ is summable by $(2)$.

**Edit:** A massive shortcut. If a positive sequence $\{b_n\}$ is such that $\sum {b_n}$ is convergent, then $\sum n b_n^2 $ is convergent too, since $\{n b_n\}$ must be bounded in order that $\sum b_n$ converges. So we can just use this lemma and $(2)$ to prove our claim.

Comment: Your equation $(2)$ tells us that the series $\sum b_n$, where $b_n = \sqrt{n}/(\sqrt{a_1^2+\cdots + a_n^2})\ge 0$ converges, consequently, the series $\sum b_n^4$ converges, no?

Comment: @user37238: yes for sure, but that gives just that $$\sum\frac{n^2}{(a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2)^{\color{red}{2}}}$$ is converging.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks.

Comment: Polya-Knopp's inequality how to prove it?

Comment: @NewZealand: both Hardy's and Polya-Knopp's inequalities can be proved through Bocharova's inequality, that is an extension of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @NewZealand: otherwise, see page 141 here: http://poisson.phc.unipi.it/~daurizio/Chap4.pdf  (it is in Italian, hope you can understand it)

Comment: can you prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k^2}{a^2_{1}+\cdots+a^2_{k}}\le\left(\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}\right)^2$>

Comment: @NewZealand: Now I proved $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2}{a_1^2+\ldots+a_k^2}\leq\frac{9}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2$$ in your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176292/this-inequality-sum-k-1n-frack2a2-1-cdotsa2-k-le-left-frac/1176599#1176599.