# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_k)b_k}{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k}<2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i^2}{a_i}$

Tags: inequality

How do I prove this?
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_k)b_k}{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k}<2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i^2}{a_i}$$
Here $a_i,b_i\in\Bbb R^+$. I guess the sum transform works, but I can't prove it.

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1004517

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks for your hint.Used the CS,I Got the Generalized Titu Lemma,but I can't prove the above one.

Comment: Here is a simple inequality for $b_i = 1$ :
$$\sum\frac{k}{a_1+\cdots+a_k}<2\sum\frac{1}{a_i}$$
that I can prove.

Comment: Have a look at the Polya-Knopp inequality: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167832/sum-n-1-infty-fracn2a2-1a2-2-cdotsa2-nis-also-convergen

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_k=b_1+\ldots +b_k$ and $A_k=a_1+\ldots+a_k$.  Moreover, let $a_0=b_0=A_0=B_0=0$.

We may notice that:
$$ B_n^2-B_{n-1}^2 = (B_n-B_{n-1})(B_n+B_{n-1}) = b_n (2B_n-b_n) = 2b_n B_n - b_n^2 \tag{1}$$ 
hence:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{B_k b_k}{A_k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{B_k^2-B_{k-1}^2}{A_k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b_k^2}{A_k}.\tag{2} $$
By Titu's lemma we have:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{b_k^2}{a_k}\geq \frac{B_m^2}{A_m} \tag{3}$$
and by summation by parts we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{B_k^2-B_{k-1}^2}{A_k} = \frac{B_n^2}{A_n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{B_k^2 a_{k+1}}{A_k A_{k+1}}\tag{4} $$
The claim can be proved by $(2),(3),(4)$ and induction on $n$.

Comment: Thank you.but I don't know the induction means. I got  it need to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{B_k^2a_{k+1}}{A_kA_{k+1}}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{b_k^2}{A_k} \leq   \frac{3B_n^2}{A_n}$$
and didn't know how to use induction.
would you give me some more hints?

Answer (score 0):

Here is An answer by [toshihiro shimizu](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/user/984) on [AoPS](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u113828h1289401p6815724):

I considered this problem long time and finally I found the following **inductive solution**. I'd like to know the direct solution.

We show the following stronger result by induction;
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} & \frac{\left(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{k}\right)b_{k}}{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{k}}\leq\frac{3}{2}\frac{b_{1}^{2}}{a_{1}}+2\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{b_{k}^{2}}{a_{k}}.
\end{align*}$$
$n=1$ is obvious. We assume the result of $n=1$ and we show the
result of $n$. Applying the inductive result to $\left(a_{1}+a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}\ldots,a_{n},b_{1}+b_{2},b_{3},b_{4},\ldots,b_{n}\right)$

we have
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left(b_{1}+b_{2}\right)^{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}} & +\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\left(b_{1}+\cdots+b_{k}\right)b_{k}}{a_{1}+\cdots+a_{k}}\leq\frac{3}{2}\frac{\left(b_{1}+b_{2}\right)^{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}}+2\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{b_{k}^{2}}{a_{k}}
\end{align*}$$
It's sufficient to show that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{b_{1}^{2}}{a_{1}}+\frac{\left(b_{1}+b_{2}\right)b_{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(b_{1}+b_{2}\right)^{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}} & \leq\frac{3}{2}\frac{b_{1}^{2}}{a_{1}}+2\frac{b_{2}^{2}}{a_{2}}\\
\frac{b_{1}^{2}+4b_{1}b_{2}+3b_{2}^{2}}{a_{1}+a_{2}} & \leq\frac{b_{1}^{2}}{a_{1}}+4\frac{b_{2}^{2}}{a_{2}}\\
b_{1}^{2}+4b_{1}b_{2}+3b_{2}^{2} & \leq b_{1}^{2}+\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}b_{1}^{2}+4\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}b_{2}^{2}+4b_{2}^{2}\\
4b_{1}b_{2} & \leq\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}b_{1}^{2}+4\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}b_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}
\end{align*}$$
The last inequality is true since
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}b_{1}^{2}+4\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}b_{2}^{2} & \geq2\sqrt{\frac{a_{2}}{a_{1}}b_{1}^{2}\cdot4\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}}b_{2}^{2}}\\
& =4b_{1}b_{2}
\end{align*}$$
, completing the proof.