# Convergence of nested series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Prove that the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$$ implies the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(n^2a_n\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\bigg)^{-2}\bigg).$$

Actually I have no idea about where to start this. I tried few of the relevant series convergence tests, but none of them worked. Any detailed help will be appreciated.

Comment: A complete solution is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200514/contest-problem-about-convergent-series?rq=1. This is quite the non-trivial homework problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contest problem about convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200514/contest-problem-about-convergent-series)